# Alternative for Java String array for performance

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am using a few 4 dimensional and 3 dimensional Java String arrays. The reason for using a String array is I have a mixture of data types. Although approximately 85% of the array is NULL, 10% is Integer that is converted to String to store in the String array and 5% are actual String. I have to access these arrays very frequently to first store the information and then access them again for processing.

Now it seems to me this is causing a huge increase in run-time since I have to process very large files, files in the size of a few GBs. What other data structure can be useful in this case especially to improve the run time as well as memory?

Comment: "The reason for using a String array is I have a mixture of data types" sounds like a reason not to use a `String[]`.

Comment: If 85% of the array is null, you might want to consider some sort of sparse array instead.

Comment: Which data structure should be used for a mixture of data types? @AndyTurner

Comment: @MDAbidHasan you should rather use an array of Object and check the instance at Runtime, this is more efficient in space and probably less time consuming that parsing the Strings back to integer. About the sparse array, it depends on the number and type of accesses you do on the array. If you need complete random access then the sparse implementation maybe is not fit for you.

Comment: You should provide some code and more background about your data to make clear what you want to archive... is it really a mixture of data or just some kind of object hierarchy...
I.e. is it really necessary to store "null" values?

Comment: @Adrian By the mixture of data I mean, I have to read a file and store the count or string value from the file reading. And no the NULL has no use so I don't need to store it.

Comment: Most likely, not knowing ... really anything ... about your data, the innermost arrays should probably be replaced by objects with named and typed fields. E.g. `String[][] x = { { "John", "Doe", null, "42" }, ... }` should really be `Person[] x = { new Person("John", "Doe", null, 42), ... }`, so each value can be statically typed.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for using a String array is I have a mixture of data types

Sounds like a reason not to use a `String[]`.

Consider that if you're storing an `int` as a `String`, you are storing:

- A number of `chars`
- The length of the array of `char`
- Fields for things like the `hashCode`

Whereas if you store an `int` in an `Integer`, you are storing:

- The `int`.

There are other bits of overhead, but an `int` takes up the space of 2 `char`s. So `String` is a pretty inefficient way to store the majority of your non-null data.

Store things in `Object` arrays, if you must, which can hold both `String` and `Integer` instances, and then check the type of the element before using it.

If 85% of your array really is null, you should consider using some sort of sparse array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give (or point me) an example of a sparse array in this case?